# Views of the the Rabbis on the organization הוד

Tags: eretz-yisrael, sexuality, homosexuality

What do the orthodox rabbis of different circles have to say about the organization [הוד](http://hod.org.il). הוד is a support group for homosexuals trying to reconcile their sexuality with their religious beliefs. Is this considered a legitimate and halichicaly permisable source of support for Orthodox Jews suffering in this regard?

Comment: I suspect that it would be a huge controversy. On the one hand, you have rabbanim such as R' Shmuel Kamenetsky, who AFAIK is a proponent for "conversion therapy" (for fromm gays, not for gerut). On the other hand, you have those rabbanim who are more open to those of alternate sexualities, even if they disapprove of their life choices (I don't know of any notable ones off the top of my head).

Comment: Considering that centralized religious authority no longer exists due to the disbanding of the Sanhedrin, it might be hard to delineate opinions purely by "circles" or organizations, as some orgs might not have an expressed opinion, and some individuals might not agree with their orgs opinion on this particular subject.

Comment: I didn't read through the website, but what did you mean by 'reconcile'? If by reconcile it means validating the feelings that one has and the challenges it comes with, and trying to still live a Torah life, then I don't think there would be an issue. If reconcile in this case means trying to explain how it isn't forbidden according to the Torah to live that lifestyle, then I could imagine that most Torah authorities are against it (just like they're against any group i.e. Conservative and Reform, who disregard precepts of the Torah to accommodate their personal actions and beliefs).